# naudio Can't dispose of Asio when using MultiplexingWaveProvider

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, asio

If I create an AsioOut and use the MultiplexingWaveProvider it works fine (plays / disposes etc..) only if I call AsioOut.Stop() before MultiplexingWaveProvider has run out of data.

If I wait until the MultiplexingWaveProvider has run out of data (and AsioOut has triggered a PlaybackStopped event) I can't Dispose of AsioOut it just hangs and never returns (no error). Note: there is no Dispose() on the MultiplexingWaveProvider, but I've tried calling dispose on the all WaveFileReaders that are used for the MultiplexingWaveProvider.

Comment: Mark Heath's response is correct. See my code below on how I handled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a couple of people report issues with ASIO drivers when trying to automatically stop. Probably some drivers don't like it if stop is called within the buffer swap callback.

Ideally `AsioOut` should be updated to offer an option to disable auto stopping. You could simulate this by creating a never-ending `ISampleProvider` whose `Read` method returns silence after the end of the source has been reached. Then you could poll to see when the end of your input had been reached, and then `Stop` and `Dispose` when its done

Comment: I tried a third (I've been testing with two) ASIO device and it works with the auto-stop. I'll work on the ISampleProvider. For the record: I had issues with Asio4All  and a Behringer x32 (my NI Traktor worked)

Answer (score 0):

This is my implimentaion of Mark's answer. I had to use the IWaveProvidor because the MultiplexingWaveProvider I am using doesn't support the ISampleProvidor. (I could have also implemented a MultiplexingWaveProvider to get the same result I think). Note the task used to not have the stop being called inside the data handler.

```
  public class AsioWavProvidor :IWaveProvider
        {
            private bool EndSignaled = false;
            public Action EndofAudioData;
            public Mp3FileReader Mp3Reader;
            public AsioWavProvidor(string mp3File)
            {
                Mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3File);
            }
            public TimeSpan CurrentTime { get { return Mp3Reader.CurrentTime; } }


 public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                var retCount = Mp3Reader.Read(buffer, offset, count);
                if (retCount == 0)
                {
                   if (EndofAudioData != null && !EndSignaled)
                    {

                        EndSignaled = true;
                        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                EndofAudioData();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    return count;
                }
                return retCount;
            }
```